# Can G Spreadsheet email notify me, which specific person edited the sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a purchase spreadsheet where our sales people add their order. I would like google to notify me by email the moment someone finished adding their orders. The best I can make google do is tell me that "it made changes from 6/4/18 9:58 AM to 9:58 AM"

Is there a way to mention which specific person made the changes in the notification email? If my IT guy adjusts the google sheet, then I know I do not have to look for addition sales orders.

Does anyone know of any specific scripts?

Comment: Have you tried the built-in notification feature of Google Sheets? If so, why they don't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

From [Turn on notifications in a spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/91588?hl=en)Google Sheets built-in notifications

> **See who makes changes**
>
> You can see who makes changes to your spreadsheet, depending on your
>   [level of access](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494822) to a spreadsheet.
>
> - If you’re an editor: You can see the usernames of people who make changes.
> - If you’re a viewer: You can set notifications but can’t see usernames.
> - If you want to set more specific notification rules, for example when someone modifies a certain range of cells, use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview).

Reference

  -

Comment: But as an editor is there a way that the email notification can mention in the email that for example "Bob the sales person" made an edit, as opposed to "Ben the IT guy"?
If Ben made an edit I would not be interested, but if Bob made an edit I would be keen to see what kind of edits he made.

Basically I want the email to mention which specific person made a change in the sheet. 
How can I make this possible?